# Python list(set(list(...)) to remove duplicates

Tags: python, list, set

Is

```
list(set(some_list))
```

a good way to remove duplicates from a list?   (Python 3.3 if that matters)

(Edited to address some of the comments... it was perhaps too terse before).

Specifically,

- is it at least comparable, in terms of efficiency (mainly speed but also memory), if not better than writing ones own algorithm; it's clearly the most concise code
- is it reliable?  any situations where it breaks?  (one has been mentioned already ... list items need to be hashable)
- is there a more Pythonesque way of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say good?

Comment: Yes, sure. So what is your question?

Comment: What are your metrics for determination of good? What alternatives are being compared against? Is this in terms of time complexity and/or memory consumption?

Comment: Not if the list items aren't hashable.

Comment: Do you need to maintain the order of items in the list?

Comment: Order - often no.  Clearly that's an issue in some cases, in some others may even be a bonus (it seems that set(...) may in fact sort at least in some cases, based on some very limited testing).

Comment: If `set` sorts your elements, it's an accident. You shouldn't count on it.

Comment: Looks good to me as well. If you're using Numpy, you can also do `new_list = numpy.unique(some_list)`.

Comment: @EelkeSpaak that's worth an answer.

Comment: I guess Pythonic (sorry not Pythonesque, my bad) includes use of libraries, the trick is knowing which library I guess.

Comment: @MarkRansom, yeah I was in doubt whether to add as answer or comment. I trust you and your massive rep, so now added as an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The method you show is probably shortest and easiest to understand; that would make it Pythonic by most definitions.

If you need to preserve the order of the list, you can use `collections.OrderedDict` instead of `set`:

```
list(collections.OrderedDict((k, None) for k in some_list).keys())
```

Edit: as of Python 3.7 (or 3.6 if you're trusting) it's not necessary to use `OrderedDict`; a regular `dict` shares the property of retaining insertion order.  So you can rewrite the above:

```
list({k: None for k in some_list}.keys())
```

If the elements aren't hashable but can be sorted, you can use `itertools.groupby` to remove duplicates:

```
list(k for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(some_list)))
```

Edit: the above can be written as a list comprehension which some might consider more Pythonic.

```
[k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(sorted(some_list))]
```

Answer (score 4):

(As suggested in the comments, adding this comment as an answer as well.)

Your own solution looks good and pretty Pythonic to me. If you're using Numpy, you can also do `new_list = numpy.unique(some_list)`. This more or less 'reads like a sentence', which I believe is always a good benchmark for something being "Pythonic".

Answer (score 1):

To preserve order the shortest (*starting from Python 2.7*):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys('abracadabra'))
['a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd']
```

If there is no need to preserve order `list(set(...))` is just fine.

Comment: I didn't know about `fromkeys`, and I forgot that `list` will return just the keys. Your answer is much simpler than mine, +1.